# Reassignment of void pointers in C

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am making Binary Tree is C. I know how to make Binary trees, that's not the issue over here.

I was using void pointers for root and all the elements that will be added to the tree.

When the binary tree is empty(root is pointing to NULL) I was simply making the root point towards the element that will be becoming the first element of the tree. But root wasn't getting the address of the element it should be pointing to. It was just a simple re-assignment.

As I mentioned above, I was trying simple re-assignment for void pointers to assign a new address for the root.

But when I was assigning the individual values of the element to the root, everything seemed worked perfectly fine.

Represent all the elements for the binary tree.

```
struct node {

  void * key;
  void * value;
  struct node * left;
  struct node * right;

};
```

First approach: simple re-assignment which fails

```
void map_tree_put(struct node * root, struct node * ele){

    if(root==NULL) {
      root = ele;
    }
    else {
      /* some other code*/
    }

}
```

Second approach: individual value assignment works fine

```
void map_tree_put(struct node * root, struct node * ele){

    if(root==NULL) {
      root->key = ele.key;
      root->value = ele.value;
      root->left = NULL;
      root->right = NULL;
    }
    else {
      /* some other code*/
    }

}
```

Test code

```
int main() {

  struct node * r = NULL;

  int key = 10;
  int value = 100;
  struct node ele = {&key, &value, NULL, NULL};

  map_tree_put(r, &ele);

  printf("%d\n", *(int*)r->key); /* I get segmentation fault over here with the first approach but work fine with the second approach */


  return 0;

}
```

Comment: In C all arguments are passed *by value* which means they are copied, and all you have in the function is a *local* copy. There are two solutions: *Return* the new pointer and assign in the caller; Or research *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
void map_tree_put(struct node ** root, struct node * ele){
if((*root)==NULL) {
      (*root) = ele;
    }
    else {
      /* some other code*/
    }

}
```

and call from `main` should be 
  `map_tree_put(&r, &ele);`

This is about passing by value and reference.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in this code:

```
void map_tree_put(struct node * root, struct node * ele){

    if(root==NULL) {
      root = ele;
    }
    else {
      /* some other code*/
    }
}
```

the function receives a *copy* of the pointers. To make the `root` pointer remember the re-assignment when the function returns, you need to do it like this:

```
void map_tree_put(struct node **root, struct node *ele){
  if (root) {
    if(*root==NULL) {
      *root = ele;
    }
    else {
      /* some other code*/
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The condition should then really be `if (root != NULL && *root == NULL)`